# JavaScript date math not working

Tags: javascript, datepicker, getdate

I have searched this forum and found many useful answers, but one of the answers that I used only works under certain conditions.

I am populating a week calendar, and simply need to determine the start of the week (Monday) from a Date picker, and then I add to that date to populate text fields with the following 6 days. This works only if the date picker selection is in the same month.

So, if I select Wednesday May 15th 2013, it correctly returns and populates the Monday with May 13, the Tuesday with May 14, etc.

But, if I select Wednesday May 1, 2013, it correctly populates Monday Apr 29, but Tuesday it puts as May 30 (adding a month instead of a day).

I should note that I am building this in Application Craft, so I don't know if that has any impact.

Here's my code:

```
var curr = new Date(app.getValue("DatePicker2")); // get selected date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() +1; // Adjust for monday start of week
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
var secondday = new Date();
secondday.setDate(firstday.getDate()+1);
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Thanks

Tammy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

`secondday.setDate(firstday.getDate()+1)`

since you are specifying only the date in the setDate function, it would assume "this" month which happens to be `May` in this case

So, you can do

```
secondday = new Date(firstday.getFullYear(), firstday.getMonth(), firstday.getDate()+1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie and am self teaching myself javascript.  I thought that getDate was for the date, getMonth was for the month.  i don't know exactly what you mean?  Or how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, in fact it makes both situations fail (when you select May 15, it now puts the Monday as the proper May 13 and the Tuesday as (Sat) May 4.  When you select May 1st, it puts the proper Apr 29 as Monday but (Fri) May 3 as the Tuesday.  ?

Comment: can you check the edit. I was resetting the month to current month.